# How to compare consecutive List of lists on a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, compare

I have a dataframe that have a column that containts a list of lists,that means that every value in this column is a list of strings .So, i want to compare two consecutive values from this column.
PS: the strings in the lists are not ordered

Comment: Add your code, example of your dataframe  and errors that you get, please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.